# Write terminal output to text

Tags: linux, terminal

I use raspberry pi terminal command to get mac address and their rssi, can I import these data into txt/xlsx or other tools that can be saved while the terminal displays them?

Comment: try: `ifconfig >> output.txt` The “>” is the output redirection operator used for overwriting files that already exist in the directory. While, the “>>” is an output operator as well, but, it appends the data of an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `tee` command, e.g.

```
ifconfig | tee output.txt
```

will write the output of ifconfig to the terminal and at the same time save it in output.txt.